# Mongodb Atlas Search with directive insensitive

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am using MongoDB Atlas Search to perform a search in Collection, for this I created a Atlas Search Index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "caption": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my aggregation:

```
[
   {
      "$search":{
         "text":{
            "path":"caption",
            "query":"Ingocnitáá",
            "fuzzy":{
               
            }
         },
         "highlight":{
            "path":"caption"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I have below document in my collection:

```
{caption:"Ct tyu test Ingocnitáá"}
```

Issue: When I searching `Ingocnitaa` agreegation returning 0 result.

Is there anything wrong with my Search Index? I want an directive insensitive  Search with highlight.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things missing:

1. Include index name (Recommend to not use a default index, create a new index)
2. Always pass `fuzzy:{}`

Here is a working query:

```
[
  {
       "$search":{
          "index": 'messageText',
          "text":{
             "path":"caption",
             "query":"Ingocnitaa",
             "fuzzy":{

             }
          },
          "highlight":{
             "path":"caption"
          }
       }
    }
]
```

Where `messageText` is search index name.

---

Search Index Formattion:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "caption": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [CLick here](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-atlas-search-with-directive-insensitive/13912/2)

Comment: Would this work with `"query":"Ingocnitáá"` instead of `"query":"Ingocnitaa?`

Comment: yes it works with both